# Why is the town called "Trinity"?

Tags: name-significance, religion, the-heir-chronicles, cinda-williams-chima

The action in Cinda Williams Chima's *The Heir Chronicles* centers around Trinity, Ohio. The town name is almost obnoxiously religious. Religion, specifically Christianity, does come up in the books, too: Seph, for one, is a devout Catholic, some of the other characters are vaguely Christian in a non-churchgoing way, and churches suppress magic to the point that "churching" someone injured by a wizard is a legitimate treatment. So I assume that the name isn't an accident. What is its significance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The town of Trinity is, according to the [Fandom Wiki](https://heirchronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Trinity,_Ohio) based on the real location of [Oberlin, Ohio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberlin,_Ohio)
Oberlin [was founded](https://www2.oberlin.edu/external/EOG/OYTT/ch3.html)  by two Presbyterian ministers as

> a community of church-centered families who would live simply and according to God's commandments. This community would support a school, to be built for them, that would train preachers and Christian teachers

and was named after Alsation pastor and philanthropist [J. F. Oberlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._F._Oberlin)

My reading would be that if the town of Trinity is indeed based on Oberlin, that the relationship with Christianity is 'baked in' to the town from its founding rather than being a later evolution or even necessarily as response to the magical inhabitants, and that the name is meant to underscore that.